# Computing Turtle's Final Location with Parallel Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

The question is

"Suppose we are given an n-element array of (θ, d) tuples that represent a sequence of commands
to a turtle to first turn θ degrees counterclockwise and then move forward d units. Describe
a parallel algorithm using parallel scan and/or parallel prefix scan contexts to compute the
turtle’s final location in O(n/p + log p) time on a p-processor system."

I'm having a hard time understanding how I can use parallel processing on this, since it seems like I would need to process each tuple sequentially. In other words, it seems like previous tuples will affect the location of the turtle after processing the next tuple. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to expand the domain of the input so that we can define an associative composition operator. For this problem, a standard choice is to represent a turtle movement as the matrix that maps turtle-local coordinates `[x y 1]` to global coordinates `[x' y' 1]` (3D coordinates with an extra `1` because I'm using [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates)).

```
[x y 1] [a b 0]
        [c d 0] = [x' y' 1]
        [e f 1]
```

For a pair `(θ, d)`, we get a matrix

```
[  cos θ     sin θ   0]
[ -sin θ     cos θ   0]
[d cos θ   d sin θ   1].
```

Multiply these matrices in reverse order to get a matrix that converts step by step from the last turtle-local coordinates back to global coordinates. Map `[0 0 1]` to determine the turtle's final position (`(0, 0)` in turtle-local coordinates).